# Make javascript run on external link click?

Tags: php, javascript, hyperlink

Ok, lets say I have page.php. If i'm currently viewing page.php and I click this link:

```
<a href="#?call=friend.request&amp;user_id=10&amp;width=420&amp;height=250">Link</a>
```

The javascript box will pop up. Success!

However, if I'm on a different page, and I link to

```
<a href="http://domain.com/page.php#?call=friend.request&amp;user_id=10&amp;width=420&amp;height=250">Link</a>
```

The javascript box will not pop up when the page loads.

Any ideas?

I can't edit or find the javascript code that executes the said function, unfortunately.

Comment: Could you plz explain it in more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the idea of JS, so basically what you have to do is a check in the `window.onload` event, so you can check the `window.location` to search for the # string and then parse whatever you want.

As I said, that's not the general idea of JS, so it turn out to be a little messy.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to run a function on page load which would inspect window.location.search (which provides access to the ?call=.... part) And then calls the same javascript that the links on your page.php are calling.

Comment: metrobalderas is correct, I missed the "#" in your question. you would have to access it via window.location, not window.location.search. my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that linking to the page directly like that, it sees the `?` code as part of the querystring and not the hash thus making the hash value just an empty `#`.  Can you do this without the `?` in the hash value?  Or you can try URL encoding it using `%3F`.

```
<a href="http://domain.com/page.php#%3Fcall=friend.request&amp;user_id=10&amp;width=420&amp;height=250">Link</a>
```